# Creating automatic subscriber function

Tags: subscriptions

I currently have a subscribe section on the website I manage. If I want to access my this information I have to go through campign monitor, manually transfer the emails and manually send out content. Is there a way, if people have subscribed, that they will can automatically receive an email when any new content is published?

Answer (score 0):

IF CampaignMonitor is your preferred system to deliver new 'alerts' then you can setup an RSS feed on your site, point CM to that feed and then in CM set up a new template to send 'alerts' (daily, weekly... etc) to your mailing list.

It's described in [CM docs](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/rss-to-email/)